# Php, replace all dates (string) to DateTime class, memory issues?

Tags: java, php, datetime

Recently our management has been affected by Java developments (which is right), so our project becomes more "tipized". Thats ok, lets start to replace all dates to datetimes, so, what used to be:

```
public function setDate ($id, $date)
{
    mysql insert date ($id, $date) etc etc pseudo code
}

....

setDate ('2001-01-02 11:32:54');
```

so all dates were in raw format. After our refactoring, it should be look alike:

```
public function setDate ($id, DateTime $date)
{
    mysql insert date ($id, $date->toFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s') etc etc pseudo code
}

....

setDate (new DateTime ('2001-01-02 11:32:54'));
```

which almost have... very little advantage. But it increases the memory what script consume. In general, is it good to have "better" code to sacrifise some memory/resource?

Comment: I think that having a good code-base will stop A LOT of problems when maintaining an APP. But when we are talking about speed each minimal change will affect the overall. The key here I think is to look for the balance between key elements "Speed - Clean Code - Resources waste" but it really depend on your business requirements.